# Compare unique values with multiple columns and return the most recent

Tags: excel, compare, multiple-columns

```
--------------------------------------------------
| X |    A    |    B    |     C      |     D     |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1 | Fruit   | List    | Date       | Condition |
--------------------------------------------------
| 2 | Banana  | Banana  | 02/05/2010 | Good      |
--------------------------------------------------
| 3 | Tomato  | Banana  | 02/05/2014 | Excellent |
--------------------------------------------------
| 4 | Orange  | Banana  | 02/05/2011 | Bad       |
--------------------------------------------------
```

I would like to compare one-by-one the items in column A with column B, then return what's in column D for the most recent date in column C for that item.

E.g.: For "Banana" (A2) - Result = Excellent

I tried some INDEX with MATCH, but I can't get the correspondent MAX value.

Thanks

Comment: Please, include a code snippet or algorithm on how you plan to solve the problem, and consider formatting your post correctly to avoid downvotes. Welcome to SO.

Comment: Thanks. I am new here. I just adjusted the format, but it seems this forum doesn't have a simple way of adding tables and I don't have a "good reputation" yet to add pictures :( . Anyway, I hope it's easier to understand now. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 1):

This is an array formula.  Enter it in E2 by holding down **ctrl-shift** while hitting **enter**.  Excel will put curly braces **{...}** around the formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(List,A2),INDEX(Condition,MATCH(MAX((A2=List)*Date),(A2=List)*Date,0)),"")
```

List, Condition, and Date are named ranges corresponding to the appropriate columns.  eg:  B2:b7, C2:c7, D2:d7.

This screenshot is based on your original post, as edited by me before you edited it your way:

[image]

Comment: Hi Ron. That works perfectly! Thank you so much! I spent so much time with this and you explained so well. The array formula trick and everything. I can't thank you enough! :) Thanks for fixing my table as well :)

Comment: @Rodri Glad to help.  Since it worked, please mark my response as the answer.  Thank you.